# issue building select/drop-down optgroup with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `<optgroup>` to a drop down in JQuery. Option is working correctly but I can't get option group to work.

HTML:

```
<select name="DropDownID" id="DropDownID">
    <optgroup label="Foo">
        <option style="alignment: center" value="<%= alertGroup.colorValue %>" id="red7" selected disabled hidden><%= alertGroup.colorName %></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#DropDownID")
colorBuild(function (result) {
    var Color = result;

    for (var i = 0; i < Color.Data.length; i++) {
        $("#DropDownID").append($("<optgroup></optgroup>").attr('label', Color.Data[i].ColorText)); //<-- This is my issue
        $("#DropDownID").append($("<option></option>").val(Color.Data[i].RgbValue).text(Color.Data[i].ColorText).html(Color.Data[i].ColorName)); //<-- This is working fine

    }
});
```

My console.log

```
{element: n.fn.init(1), index: 0, value: "df514f", label: "Red", optgroup: "Foo", …} //<-- this is coming from static HTML
56d6736dfe2cf81830b7ec0f:124 {element: n.fn.init(1), index: 1, value: "df514f", label: "Red", optgroup: "", …} //<-- I want to be able to add a value here with JQuery code above
56d6736dfe2cf81830b7ec0f:124 {element: n.fn.init(1), index: 2, value: "CD69C9", label: "Orchild", optgroup: "", …}
```

This is how I get the values:

```
function GetSelectedItem(el)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(el);

    color = "The Value is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + " and text is: " + e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    colorName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    colorValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    optgroupValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].optgroup; //<-- this is resolving as undefined
}
```

Comment: `$("<optgroup></optgroup>").val('Foo2')` This `optgroup` can't contain a simple value.

Answer (score 0):

Create the group, using label for naming it, then add each option to the group..  ?

```
$("#DropDownID")
colorBuild(function (result) {
    var Color = result;

    //create a constant for element
    const $sel = $('#DropDownID');

    //create a variable to hold our optgroup
    var group = $('<optgroup/>');

    //assign label to optgroup and append to select element
    group.attr('label', 'Foo2').appendTo($sel);


    for (var i = 0; i < Color.Data.length; i++) {

        //probably only need .html here, anyway, append to group
        $('<option />').val(Color.Data[i].RgbValue).text(Color.Data[i].ColorText).html(Color.Data[i].ColorName).appendTo(group);

    }
}
```

and to get the selected optgroup...

```
optGroup = e.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. I need the optgroup to be a variable though. Sorry it wasn't clear on my question. I tried using `group.attr('label', Color.Data[i].ColorText).appendTo($sel)` inside the for loop but it didn't work. To get the selected optgroup in the 'function GetSelectedItem(el)'. I tried your solution as static but I still got `undefined`.